# Nested query in MySQL inside IF clause seems not to work as expected

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table which contains time spent on tasks described as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task_log` (
`task_log_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`task_log_task` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`task_log_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`task_log_description` text,
`task_log_creator` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`task_log_hours` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`task_log_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`task_log_project` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`task_log_stage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL )
```

The idea is to store reference to task (via task_log_task) or to stage of the project (via task_log_stage) - they reference to corresponding tables by foreign key.

I am doing a monthly worktime usage report and should have results grouped by worktime. Worktime can be spent on a task (then it has filled task_log_task (references task.task_id) and optionally task_log_stage (references stages.stage_id, may be null) or on a project (then it has task_log_project (references projects.project_id) and optionally stage filled).

I write a query that can get all these factors.

```
SELECT IF(
 `task_log_task` IS NOT NULL, 
   ( SELECT `task_project` FROM `tasks` WHERE `task_id`=`task_log_task` ),
    IF ( `task_log_project` IS NOT NULL, `task_log_project`,
     ( SELECT `stage_project_id` FROM `stages` WHERE `stage_id`=`task_log_stage` ) ) ) AS `task_project`,
 `task_log_stage`, SUM(`task_log_hours`)*3600 AS `worked_time`
 FROM `task_log`
 WHERE `task_log_creator`=$UID
 AND `task_log_date` BETWEEN $MONTH_START AND $MONTH_END
 GROUP BY `task_log_stage`
```

But it seems that it doesn't work as expected, skipping worktime that was actually used (by coincidence that was my worktime, so I detected an error quickly).

In pseudocode it should look like:

```
0. If there is task_log_task, then take task_project from tasks where task_id = current task_log_task
1. Else if there is task_log_project, then take it as task_project
2. Else if there is no task_log_project, then take task_log_stage, get stage_project_id from stages using task_log_stage as identifier, then take it as task_project
3. Get sum of monthly worked time by stage.
4. Filter them using user_id and date range.
5. ???
6. PROFIT!
```

It seems that it takes `task_id=task_log_task` literally, not putting current `task_log_task` inside the query.

Or MySQL doesn't support the thing I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have the GROUP BY wrong cause you have data grouped by  different fields: task_log_task , task_log_project and task_log_stage. 
I think you should put the formula you used  for the `task_project` field in the GROUP BY instead of the `task_log_stage` field
...

GROUP BY
IF(
 `task_log_task` IS NOT NULL, 
   ( SELECT `task_project` FROM `tasks` WHERE `task_id`=`task_log_task` ),
    IF ( `task_log_project` IS NOT NULL, `task_log_project`,
     ( SELECT `stage_project_id` FROM `stages` WHERE `stage_id`=`task_log_stage` ) ) )

ciao
Luca

Comment: It looks that you're right. I am re-reading the query and cannot understand how it worked before. It's interesting if MySQL supports IF in GROUP BY sentences

Comment: I tested the query and didn't result in error., but I have no data so I don't know if gives you back correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put `task_project` to GROUP BY and it seems to work.

So the query remains the same.